Jupyter notebook is not showing files in tree
I was opening Jupyter Notebook through command prompt and although the command worked and the app started running, the window is just pure white. I don't know what to do.
enter image description here
I was hoping for Notebook to open in it's default state so then I could code on my notebooks

I changed ports, and by running the command with --port=8887, the host loaded. I suppose there is a port conflict somewhere
